# wget -404 not found

Tags: wget

When trying to use the command line on Windows to `wget` a file, I'm getting a 404 error

```
C:\Users\xxxx>wget + http://www.restaurantanzu.com/PDFs/Dinner908.pdf;
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
--2011-06-07 15:59:19--  http://+/

Resolving . 67.199.65.121
Connecting to |67.199.65.121|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2011-06-07 15:59:21 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is the + right after the wget command? Looks like wget is trying to resolve/pull that as a URL based on the end, the "http://+/"

Try it without the +. In fact, try it with just:

```
wget http://www.restaurantanzu.com/PDFs/Dinner908.pdf
```

This works for me on a linux box.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the + (as mentioned by @baraboom) and also drop the semi-colon at the end of the line.